# How can i get the URL of a tweet?

Tags: twitter, spring-social

getUserTimeline(...) return a list of tweets. from this list there is a way to find out for each tweet, its url?
something like

```
List<Tweet> tweets = getUserTimeline("userId");
for(Tweet tweet:tweets){
    tweet.urlOfTweet(); <--------???
}
```

Comment: i've find this workaround:

String tweetUrl="http://twitter.com/"+tweet.getFromUser()+"/status/"+tweet.getIdStr();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally do it like that if you need just the URL of a specific tweet:

```
List<Tweet> tweets = getUserTimeline("userId");

for(Tweet tweet : tweets){
    //Do something with the URL
    tweet.getSource();
}
```

You can check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.html) for further details what can be accessed from each tweet.